# Passing TableViewCell to a new TableView (at the top) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**What I want to do:**
I have a feed (TableView( and once the user taps on a Post (TableViewCell), he should see a new Page (TableView) with the Post he tapped on first (the same TableViewCell) on top and a couple of comments below.

**My Problem:**
I dont get how to "clone" that TableViewCell.

Here two pictures for a better understanding:

[image: The Feed with the Post I want to clone]

[image: This is how it should look: The Post in the first section and cloned from the Cell the user clicked on]

**Some complications:**
I have multiple post types in the main feed, so the code would have to differentiate between them to see which cell type to use to display the content.

**My code:**

**Main Feed**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0{
            return mixed.count
        }
        else if section == 1{
            return phots.count
        }
        else{
            return texttt.count
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: mixedTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! mixedTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: self.mixed[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: popularTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! popularTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: self.phots[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! textTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: self.texttt[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "commentsVC")
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

**My second ViewController**

```
class CommentsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var texty = [TextComment]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        table.register(popularTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: popularTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.register(featuredTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: featuredTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.register(textTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: textTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.register(mixedTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: mixedTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.register(textComTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: textComTableViewCell.identifier)


        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self


    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        2
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0{
            return 1
        }
        else{
            return 15
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! textTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textComTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! textComTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0{
//            self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 250
//            self.table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
//            return UITableView.automaticDimension
            return 300
        }
        else{
//            self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 150
//            self.table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
//            return UITableView.automaticDimension
            return 150
        }
    }
```

**Note**
Right now the it isnt working at all, how I want it. I just have these "mock" posts as space-fillers in there.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**My structs**

```
struct PhotoPost {
    let numberOfComments: Int
    let username: String
    let timestampName: String
    let userImageName: String
    let postImageName: String
    let postID: String
}

struct TextPost {
    let numberOfComments: Int
    let username: String
    let timestampName: String
    let userImageName: String
    let textName: String
    let postID: String
}

struct MixedPhoto {
    let numberOfComments: Int
    let username: String
    let timestampName: String
    let userImageName: String
    let textName: String
    let postImageName: String
    let postID: String
}
```

**Here my errors:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did i understand you correctly that you just need to "render" exactly the same cell which was clicked on a different controller and instance of `UITableView`?

Comment: yes! but I would also like the keep the buttons etc functional @TheDreamsWind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of `UITableView` has its own pool of cells, for this reason it would not be correct to "steal" an instance of the cell from one `UITableView` and put it into another. Also, as far as i can see you already have a convenient way to feed your cells with data, and dequeue corresponding types. Thus the only thing left here is to pass the required data from `MainFeed` under your `tableView(_: didSelectRowAt:)` function, something like that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "commentsVC") as? CommentsViewController else {
       return
    }
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            vc.mixedData = mixed[indexPath.row]
        case 1:
            vc.photoData = photos[indexPath.row]
        default:
            vc.textData = texttt[indexPath.row]
    }
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

And then, under the `CommentsViewController`'s `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)` function, implement pretty much the same stuff you did in `MainFeed`:

```
var mixedData: MixedPhoto?
var photoData: PhotoPost?
var textData: TextPost?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell: UITableViewCell
        switch (mixedData, photoData, textData) {
        case (.some(let value), _, _):
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: mixedTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! mixedTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: value)
        case (_, .some(let value), _):
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: popularTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! popularTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: value)
        case (_, _, .some(let value)):
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! textTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: value)
        default:
            fatalError("The data is not set")
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textComTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! textComTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Also I should say that it's a good idea to implement a common protocol for your data types, so you actually can define a single non-optional variable in the `CommentsViewController` instead of three optionals.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Currently trying to implement it.

Comment: I have some issues with the implementation of the data. I also edited my structs into my question. Would you mind taking a look? @The Dreams Wind
Your answer is amazing, but I am too "noob-ish" to implement it.

Comment: @JanSwoboda hey. What kind of problem did you face? Does compiler give any errors or it's built correctly but doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I dont know how to declare the types of MixedData, PhotoData and TextComment. And in the first ViewController it tells me, that vc has no members like those that we want to pass. 
I am adding three pictures of those errors to my question. Thanks for helping me

Comment: @JanSwoboda sorry for the late answer, I've been a bit busy... Well, I was in hurry when writing this answer and without compiler made a lot of mistakes. My bad :) First error is straightforward - program is not aware of exact type of `UIViewController` returned from the storyboard, thus you need to cast it first,  its interface gets available for use. Second error is probably worth clarifying. Could you please explain why you defined `mixedData`, `photoData` and `textData` as arrays? Isn't the second VC supposed to take only one instance of these types (that was selected in the previous VC)

Comment: Having that said, the second part is also broken, thanks to my ignorance.. Of course Swift will not allow to hold values of different types under the same variable (this is a strongly typed language), so we have to change the `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)` a bit. Please refer to my code and feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: No worries! Thanks to your answer I was able to do what I wanted :) Thank you very much